# functions not working well when linked via a static lib, but working if copied in the prog

Tags: c, static-libraries, win64

I have a static lib (.a) containing some useful functions that I'm using inside another program. 
The link goes well, the functions from the lib are found, but when the program gets executed it doesn't work well. On the other hand, if I copy/paste the lib functions I need directly in my program code, it works well. Moreover, it was working well on win32, but now I'm on Win64.

**Edit: I know the code is horrible (it's not mine), but it IS working when directly copied in the prog, which mean the developper won't change anything about it. What i need is to understand why it does not work well when i link the library where the function is, when it was working perfectly on Linux64 and Win32. You may find a lot of problems in this code, but it's just one example; since it doesn't explain why it works in the prog but not linked by the lib, it'll be useless to me since the dev doesn't care at all.**

Here's ONE of the problematic functions in the lib (i took the simplest, which does not depends to much on the lib, but i suspect others not to work as expected):

```
#if defined(mingwx64)
typedef long long         I64;
#else
typedef long              I64;
#endif
typedef unsigned char     UI8;

void readParamFile (char* filename, UI8* *Params, I64 *ParamsLen){
    FILE* fic;
    char* buf; int buf_Len;
    *Params=NULL; *ParamsLen=0;

    if(!(fic=fopen(filename, "rb"))){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, can't open %s\n", filename);
        exit (-1);
    }
    fseek(fic, 0, SEEK_END);
    buf_Len=ftell(fic);
    fseek(fic, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if(!(buf=(char*)PtrAlloc(sizeof(char)*buf_Len))){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't allocate %d bytes", buf_Len);
        exit(-1);
    }

//the files are specifics, i read the lines until the first one which doesn't start with #
    do{
       if(!fgets(buf, buf_Len, fic)){
          fprintf(stderr,"Error: Can't read parameters");
          exit(-1);
       }
       buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';
    } while (buf[0]=='#');

    if(!(*Params= (UI8*)PtrAlloc(sizeof(UI8)*strlen(buf)))){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't allocate %d butes", buf_Len);
        exit(-1);
    }

    strncpy((char*) *Params , buf, *ParamsLen=strlen(buf));

    PtrFree(buf);
    fclose(fic);
}
```

So, this function is in MyLib.a. I compiled it on Win64 using Mingw64 (just like I used Mingw on Win32), the compilation works. 
Then, when compiling MyProg, I link this lib. The compilation goes well. 
And when I launch MyProg, it will at some point use this function, and stop on the `strncpy`  (before was `memcpy` used, but it wasn't better). It won't throw any error message, nothing: I wait a bit and the prog stops just as if it has done everything well, except it didn't. If I try to make a print after this `strncpy`, it never goes to it, but the prog end "normally" (no crash that i can see).

The weird point is, if I copy/paste this function inside the code of MyProg, let's say I call it `readFileBis`, then `readFileBis` works well.

However, i'm not going to copy/paste every function of my lib inside every prog which needs it. Would be a waste.

EDIT: tried to make a reproducible example for it, but still working on it. So let's say this is the only file of MyProg:

**MyProg.c**

```
#define FILENAME "MyDir/ParamFile.txt"

void readParamFileBis (char* filename, UI8* *Params, I64 *ParamsLen){
    //the exact same thing as in readFile, don't wanna make the question too long.
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    UI8 *Params = NULL; 
    I64 ParamsLen = 0;

//this is working:
    readParamFileBis (FILENAME, &Params, &ParamsLen);
//this is not working : 
    readParamFile (FILENAME, &Params, &ParamsLen);

    exit(0);
}
```

And ParamFile.txt looks like it (with a way more longer number):

```
# Introduction text
000500000000064F1B58372A27
```

I would like to know what may be wrong here. Knowing that it was working well on Win32, I guess it has something to do with the 64bit thing, but I don't know what. Since I recompiled both the lib and the prog on win64, it should be ok. I have no idea what's going on.

Oh, and there's another weird thing which may or may not has something to do with it: when compiling, I may use the flag -D${ARCHI}. On Win32, ARCHI was `mnigw386`; on win64, it is `mingwx64`. When I compile with this flag on Win64, I got some warnings about my print formats (like, I'm using %ld to print some I64, and it doesn't like it) that I didn't had on win32.

**EDIT/Solution:** So the problem was indeed the I64. I managed to change it by a `int64_t` and it is working. Moreover, i managed to refont the Makefiles (from 250lines and 16 targets to 90 lines and 5 targets...), and then found out that the architecture was indeed defined...but not included in any compilation flag. So i guess that the prog couldn't see that `I64` was defined as a `long long` (since it's in a `if mingwx64`) and thought it was a `long`, and that was the big prob here.

Comment: Perhaps your program *crashes*? Have you tried to use a debugger to run the program? What does it say?

Comment: By the way, `(char*) *Params` looks *very* suspect... What is the type `UI8`? If it's `unsigned char` then `*Params` is a single `unsigned char` and not really something you can use as a pointer. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please enable more verbose warnings when building (if the compiler doesn't already warn about such things). If `UI8` is an alias for a pointer type, then don't do that. Hiding pointer types makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain. And don't make up your own type-aliases, use the standard unless there's a specific semantic meaning.

Comment: should have said that the prog is not from me and i shouldn't touch it. I also doesn't like this `(char*) *Params` but it's how it is :'( 
I'm already trying to make a reproducible example, but it's using a lot of particular functions from the lib so it's hard to do. And i'm also trying to find what `UI8`and `I64`refers to. What may help is the way the function is called; i'll add that in the question.

Comment: Any reason you chose `fgets` instead of `fread` to handle the read of binary data? You may well have a `0xa` char in your binary data that would cause the read to stop prematurely, and you may well have a `0x0` in your data that would cause `strcpy` to stop prematurely as well. Bad juju to mix string functions with a binary read.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: i'm not allowed to change this `typedef long I64`. It comes from another lib, i put it here just to let you know exactly what was those I64 and UI8. I can't change them. In fact, if there wer an answer which doesn't involve changing the code, but instead add something to the dev environment, it would be perfect -_-

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Frankly, i have no idea. I didn't made it, i barely understand what it does. The code is given to me; i can make litlle changes, but as less as possible. My point is just to make it works on every OS.

Comment: I got you. That is a big problem. In your function, you open `fic=fopen(filename, "rb")` in binary mode. If `filename` contains binary data, and not just plain-old-text, then you should not be using `fgets` as binary data has no concept of what a line is. The ASCII value for the `'\n'` is `0xa` (10) which may just as easily be the low-byte in a `short` with value `6922`. The *nul-character* `0x0` may just be the high byte in the `short` 10 in a binary file, but if you pass the buffer to `strcpy` and the first two bytes in the file as a `short 10` (e.g. `0000000000001010`) nothing is copied.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin then, why is it working when the function's code is in my prog? And why is it working on Win32 and Linux64?

Comment: If your file contains plain-old-text, there is no problem. But without knowing what your content actually is, all I can go by is the `fic=fopen(filename, "rb")` opening. If it is working, then you are fine. You can remove the `'b'` from the `mode` to eliminate the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code fragments posted:

- `#define FILENAME "MyDir\ParamFile.txt"` is incorrect. You should either escape the backslashes as `#define FILENAME "MyDir\\ParamFile.txt"` or use plain forward slashes that work with all Windows versions: `#define FILENAME "MyDir/ParamFile.txt"`
- The arbitrary definition of type `I64` is risky. You should include `<stdint.h>` and use `typedef uint64_t I64;`
- the function prototype `void readFile(char* filename, UI8 *Params, I64 *ParamsLen)` is inconsistent with the expected API: `readFile` reads the file contents and stores a pointer to an allocated buffer of length `*ParamsLen` into `*Params`. The prototype should be:

  ```
  int readFile(const char *filename, UI8 **Params, I64 *ParamsLen);
  ```

  `readFile` should return an error code in case the file cannot be open or read.
- There is a missing `}` after `exit (-1);` in function `readFile`.
- The temporary buffer should be allocate with an extra byte, just in case the file contains a single line not terminated with a newline.
- `fgets()` does not necessarily store a `'\n'` at the end of the array, especially if the file does not contain one. Stripping the last character unconditionally is incorrect.
- why not use `malloc()` instead of the non portable Windows specific `PtrAlloc()`.
- If you expect to use the file contents as a C string, you should allocate an extra byte for the null terminator and store it at the end of the array.

This function uses a contorted approach to read a line from a file. You should try harder to understand what it does and fix it from the above remarks. C is a sharp and unforgiving language, programming without a good understanding of the elements used leads to bugs and failures with maximum frustration.

The main issue in and around this code is the definition of type `I64`. Due to the overwhelming amount of non portable Win32 code that assumed `long` to be exactly 32-bits, Microsoft decided to keep `long` 32-bits on Win64 and to make matters worse delayed support for standard 64-bit types in the C library, making `%lld` non portable to Microsoft Windows default libraries. This explains the warning you get from the gcc compiler that checks the consistency of `printf` arguments with the format string. If it *worked* in the win32 version, they probably did not use 64 bit values (`long long`) at all.

A possible explanation for the different behavior between the static library and embedding the functions' code in the program is the use of different compilers, compiler options or command line definitions. Did you check all these? Do you compile the library yourself or do you get it in binary form from a different team?

Porting software between 32- and 64-bit architectures is non-trivial, especially on Windows platforms that encouraged non portable constructs and have flaky C99 support.

The code is not only poorly written, the prototype for the function is incorrect: `Params` is not a `UI8 *` it should be a `UI8 **`, the function *works* by chance and it will break easily. If the *developper* won't change anything about it, I suggest a few possible solutions:

- copy the functions locally, fix the problems and don't use the bogus library,
- write your own functions.
- find yourself a better job at a different company: you are wasting your time there, you will learn so much more from a saner environment.

Comment: Well, for this one i can make a local copy. But i think others have a weird behavior and i don't want to copy the whole lib -_- i've tried to re-wrote it, but i still have to use parts of the lib (like, i really can't get rid of those UI8 and I64), so there's still problems. 
The company is not the problem. The dev is the client here :'(

Comment: @Ablia: *The dev is the client here :'(*  you have all my sympathy. Do you compile the library yourself or do you link to a binary they provide?

Comment: `gcc` does not have flaky C99 support.

Comment: @Joshua: gcc is fine, but VS had little support for C99 and the combination gcc+MS runtime library used by the OP is problematic: its implementation of `printf` does not support many of the c99 standard modifiers, such as `ll`, `z`, `t`...

Comment: @chqrlie i'm compiling the lib myself. But the Makefile is as horrible as the code. I'm working on simplifying it (a lot). It's actually 240 lines and 15 targets just to put 6 .c files in a lib -_- (using another lib, that i don't compile myself, but this one should be ok)

Comment: @chqrlie about the I64 thing: here the architecture is define as mingwx64, so accordint to the `if defined` I64 is a `long long`. If windows keep `long` as 32-bits, then `long long` should be 64 bits. And on Win32, `I64` was then defined only as `long`, so 32 bits.

Comment: Given the sloppiness of the configuration tests, you need to ensure that all modules are compiled with the same settings and that these settings do not conflict with each other nor are redefined locally in some of the sources...

Comment: I came to the same conclusion: `I64` must have been defined as `long` in the Win32 version, hence 32 bits! 64-bit support is cumbersome in applications that use the Microsoft Win32 runtime libraries, but naming a 32-bit type `I64` is downright evil. Although in this case, the situation is more likely attributable to stupidity and ignorance rather than malice. The system *works* by miracle in some architectures, I'm afraid your job is not to fix the problems, but rather to find the magical spells that will hide the problems for your targets.  A blatant illustration of Sturgeon's principle.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is LLP64 not LP64; your I64 ended up being only 32 bits only when compiling for x64 and the high bits passed as garbage.

Do `#include <stdint.h>` and use the types such as `int64_t` and `uint64_t` to avoid bugs like these.

Not correcting the incorrect definitions is not going to work. Use a build process that applies patches if you have to, but use working type definitions.

Comment: If that was the problem, then the function shouldn't work even when i copy it in my file, right? 

My problem is, since it works when i copy/paste the function in my file, the dev will say that it doesn't comes from the code, and then he won't change anything.

Comment: @Ablia Same file? Nope. The optimizer is squashing the bug because it can see the bad conversion now.

Comment: @Ablia *If that was the problem, then the function shouldn't work even when i copy it in my file*  Maybe, maybe not.  A botched call can work in some cases and fail in others.

Comment: @Joshua *The optimizer is squashing the bug because it can see the bad conversion now.* Or maybe the register layout is different and it just works because the proper value just happens to be in the expected register.  There are lots of reasons why undefined behavior can "work" sometimes but not others.

Comment: On Win32, `I64`is defined as `long`, so 32 bits; it's working. 
On Win64, `I64`is defined as `long long` (see the `if defined mingwx64`, so 64 bits, not 32. I can try to use `int64_t`instead, but as said those types come from another lib that i have to use and can't change at all, so i'll have to cast it back to `I64` later...

Comment: @Ablia In my opinion no option. The bad code in the library must be fixed.

Comment: I've tried 3 ways: 1) change the I64 type: `typedef int64_t I64` in the lib. Not working better than before. 2) change the readParamFile function so that it takes a int64_t instead of I64, then cast to I64 later when i need it. Working, but i need to cast a lot and this is not really a "solution". 3) just to limit the number of cast: since strncpy is the one who crash, make a `int64_t tmpVar` in the readParamFile function, and at the end of it cast `*ParamsLen = (I64) tmpVar`. Then it crash later, at the first function using ParamsLen.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - the first portion of this answer refers to the question prior to editing.  The question as originally posted had `UI8 *Param` instead of `UI8* *Param`.

========================================================================

> but it IS working when directly copied in the prog,

You haven't really established that it's working properly.  "Doesn't appear to fail" is not the same as "working properly".

Given

```
void readParamFile (char* filename, UI8 *Params, I64 *ParamsLen){
```

this code is wrong:

```
*Params=NULL
```

as `*Params` is an `unsigned char` value, not a pointer that can hold `NULL`.

So this code is wrong, too:

```
*Params= (UI8*)PtrAlloc(sizeof(UI8)*strlen(buf))
```

Again, `*Params` is a single `unsigned char` value.

That's not questionable - it is wrong to assign a pointer of any value to `*Params` given the `UI8 *Params` definition of the variable.  It's incorrect code and undefined behavior.

The code *appears* as if it would be better suited to a

```
void readParamFile (char* filename, UI8 **Params, I64 *ParamsLen)
```

declaration.

The code as posted relies on questionable-at-best `typedef`'s, and has unneeded functionality - there's no need to get the file length, for example.

Something like this is simpler, doesn't rely on non-standard `typedef`'s, and should work a lot better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int readParamFileBis( const char *filename, unsigned char **params, uint64_t *paramsLen )
{
    *params = NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        return( -1 );
    }

    // assume we have POSIX getline()
    // (Windows implementations abound...)
    unsigned char *line = NULL;
    size_t lineLen = 0UL;

    // loop until a line that doesn't start with # is found
    for ( ;; )
    {
        ssize_t bytesRead = getline( &line, &lineLen, fp );

        // EOF - no more to read
        if ( bytesRead == -1 )
        {
            break;
        }

        // line starts with # - skip it
        if ( line[ 0 ] == '#' )
        {
            continue;
        }

        // we found the first line that
        // doesn't start with #, so pass
        // it back to the caller

        // strip any trailing newline
        line[ strcspn( "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        // assume we have POSIX strdup()
        // (could just do *params = line; but
        // line could now refer to a vary large buffer
        // if a long comment line was in the file)
        *params = strdup( line );

        // tell the caller how long the line is
        // (extraneous as it's a string, but...)
        *ParamsLen = strlen( line );

        free( line );

        // found the line, so break the loop
        break;
    }

    fclose( fp );

    // didn't find a line that doesn't start with '#'
    if ( *params == NULL )
    {
         return( -1 );
    }

    // success
    return( 0 );
}
```

For Windows, it's not hard to find `getline()` and `strdup()` implementations.

Even simpler - return the string (simplified and comments removed to make it as short as possible):

```
char *readParamFile( char* filename )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL ) return( NULL );

    unsigned char *line = NULL;
    size_t lineLen = 0UL;

    for ( ;; )
    {
        ssize_t bytesRead = getline( &line, &lineLen, fp );
        if ( bytesRead == -1 ) break;
        if ( line[ 0 ] == '#' ) continue;

        line[ strcspn( "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        break;
    }

    fclose( fp );

    // oops!  Don't return a comment line!
    // could also strdup( line ) in loop above after finding proper line
    if ( line != NULL && line[ 0 ] == '#' )
    {
        free( line );
        line = NULL:
    }
    return( line );
}
```

That's all you really need to find the first line that doesn't start with a `'#'` character and return it to the caller.  It will return a pointer to the line that must be `free()`'d later on success, or `NULL` on failure.  No pointer indirection necessary.

Comment: thank's, gonna try something like this tomorrow. You're right, it doesn't fail but i'm not sure the result is good (far from it).
However, it's not a `UI8 *Param`but an `UI8* *Param` which is (i think?) equivalent to your `UI8 **Param`

Comment: @Ablia *However, it's not a `UI8 *Param` but an `UI8* *Param`* Yes, I just saw that edit.  That's a huge difference and pretty much invalidates the first few paragraphs of this answer.

Comment: @Joshua Probably because the question was edited while I was answering to replace `UI8 *Param` with `UI8* *Param`.  **HUGE** difference...

Comment: yeah, taht was a typo from me, sorry abouth that. Your answer is still helpfull and I upvoted it. I'm not sure if I have strdup or getline, but I may be able to get them (I have Mingw64 without cygwin or Msys, so it's not really POSIX)